# To find common points between contour and convexhull of an image

Tags: python, opencv, contour, convex-hull

I need to get the common points between a contour and convex hull of a hand image using python opencv.

I have computed contour and convex hull both. And do not understand how will I compute the common points between these two.

```
#import numpy;
import cv2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor



"""

#import imutils
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
image = cv2.imread('D:\SHROUTI\Miscellaneous\hand_01.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

# threshold the image, then perform a series of erosions +
# dilations to remove any small regions of noise
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)

# find contours in thresholded image, then grab the largest
# one
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] 
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
#sorting contours wrt contour area
cnt = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
#getting the largest contour
#largestcontour = cnt[0][1]
#for c in cnts:(this was in the original)
    # compute the center of the contour
M = cv2.moments(c)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
cv2.drawContours(image, cnt[0], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
cv2.putText(image, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
 # create hull array for convex hull points
hull = []
hull=cv2.convexHull(cnt[0], returnPoints=False)
Cnt = cnt[0]
pts = np.array(hull)
#defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt[0],pts)  
#cv2.drawContours(image, hull, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)   
#cv2.polylines(image, hull, True, (0, 255, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your main goal here; what are "common points" for you? The convex hull is a subset of the contour (points) you provide. So, by definition all convex hull points are (also) contour points, see the documentation on [`cv2.convexHull`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga014b28e56cb8854c0de4a211cb2be656) for more information.

Comment: Kindly supply the images you are using so that we know what you are referring to, thank you.

Comment: Actually I have image of a hand with fingers and palm. Now I have determined the convex hull and the contour individually. My aim is to determine the fingertips. I want to get the points of the convex hull which particularly residing on contour line.

Comment: I want to use K curvature algorithm here, and to I want to apply this algorithm on the coordinates of the contour which matches with some points of the convex hull